# Popup asp.net window using jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

What I am trying to do is click a link and have my webpage open as a popup not go to the webpage.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="caseloads" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None"
   Font-Size="12.5px" BackColor="#FFFFFF" CssClass="mGrid" OnSorting="caseloads_Sorting"
   AllowSorting="true">
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <a id="popup" href='erAlerts.aspx?id=<%#Eval("ClientKey") %>'>View</a>
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Client ID" SortExpression="ClientKey">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="clientKey" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ClientKey")%>' />
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Full Name" SortExpression="ConsumerName">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="clientKey" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ConsumerName")%>' />
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Program" SortExpression="pgmName">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="clientKey" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("pgmName")%>' />
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="House" SortExpression="phoneH">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="clientKey" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("phoneH")%>' />
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cell" SortExpression="phoneC">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="clientKey" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("phoneC")%>' />
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

So when I click "View" I want to be able to go to display my erAlerts.aspx.
I have tried a some but they either don't seem to work or they will open then redirect me to the page anyways after close.

I had a working one before but forgot to make a backup of it and for some reason I am lost. I can't for the life of me figure out how I did it.

Comment: Have you tried iFrame? Just add JS code to update `src` tag of iFrame to the url and add iFrame to popup.

Comment: I feel so bad for not even thinking of that. It worked >.> I'd accept answer but you commented